# angular2+ reactive from control validation pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

in angular 6 reactive forms.

regular expression of : `9999.99 OR 0000.99` ( 2 decimal) and not more then 10000 number, wrote below ( basically 0000.01 to 9999.99 should be acceptable)

Edit : 1 to 9999 also 0000.01 to 9999.99 also )

```
const currency ="(?!0)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$'";
    RatesFormArray.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.currency)]));
```

but it is not working. is angular reactive forms pattern validator works same way like regex syntax `new RegExp()` from javascript?

what i have tried is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-symlaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Which samples were not working?

Comment: Your regex seems wrong. you should correct it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `const currency="(?!(^0+(\.0+)?$))^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$"`  will match any number between 0 and 9999 with two decimal points  [Try here](https://regex101.com/r/EDWW2J/3)

Comment: 2 problems  - #1 :-  it is not accepting 1 to 9999 #2: not sure what need to put in `const currency`

Comment: 0 to 0000.00 is allowed in your regex! price cannot be 0 right?

Comment: Added negative look ahead to check zero

Answer (score 2):

try this regex to find number between 0000.01 to 9999.99

> (/^([\d]{0,4})(.|$)([\d]{2,2}|)$/g)

above regex will match only number between 0000.01 to 9999.99, so you should add it i

```
constcurrency ="\^([\\d]{0,4})(\\.|$)([\\d]{2,2}|)$";
RatesFormArray.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.currency)]));
```

Comment: just updated my regex, please try again. i have checked same on slackbiz, its working fine there.

Comment: what number you are entering there. i see its working .
if i enter any number between 0000.01 to 9999.99 then its shows valid otherwise its shows me invalid.

Comment: try this - currency ="\^([\\d]{0,4})(\\.|$)([\\d]{2,2}|)$";

check here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vh7hat